# How to draw the vertical line in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to draw the vertical line in designing .

For example

```
Table 1
Keep your job-search confidential
Control your privacy
Reach to over 35000 recruiters
Get Job Alerts in your inbox
Apply to jobs from your Mobile
```

I want to draw vertical line both side about table1

Comment: Uhm `design-patterns` tag. Is it a joke? :-S

Comment: @zerkms: he's clearly not a native speaker. He's trying to do some visual design... so "design-patterns". :)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to draw vertical line both side about table1

CSS `border-left` and `border-right`

```
<table style="border-left: 3px solid blue; border-right: 3px solid blue">
  <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Now, how do I put text on the other side of the right vertical line?